# How do I get rid of `Wise convert`?

Tags: malware

I recently started writing automated test programs with Selenium. In the program, I am opening a Web site using a chromedriver object. My computer somehow got "infected" with a program/tool called "Wise Convert". After my Web page opens, I get a box telling me that I have successfully installed "Wise Convert".

How do I get rid of this?

Comment: What tools have you tried to remove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a toolbar that converts image formats to PDF.

In Chrome, go to chrome://extensions find Wise Convert in the list. Click uninstall or disable.

Comment: I didn't quite ask my question right, sorry.

You are right. It is a toolbar and once it is displayed, I can uninstall it as mentioned above.

It keeps on getting re-installed. When I open a Web page manually, this toolbar does not get "attached". It is only when I open a Web page using chromedriver it gets attached.

In order to try and remove it, I have 

(1) Run a full scan of Kaspersky Anti Virus program

(2) Run BitDefender

Neither found any problems/infections.

Thanks.

Comment: Check out [Other Deployment Options](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions.html). It sounds like you have an external extension installed on your machine, which is storing a key in the registry.

Comment: Your linked helped.  Removing it from the registry worked.  Thank you!

Comment: We also had to remove a crx file at AppData/Local along with about a hundred folders having the same name as the crx file. (It was a junk name like cqhjfsdyujkfduif.........crx.)

When a friend helped me remove the registry entry, he noticed that it had this weird name (i.e., cqhjfsdyujkfduif.........). We searched the C drive for files named this and found the crx file and the folders.

Thanks again for the help.